# Use of undefined constant CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1 - assumed 'CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1'

Tags: php, curl

I am using php version 5.3.10
and using curl version 7.22.0
And when I am using this code:

```
$curlOptions[CURLOPT_URL] = $absUrl;

$curlOptions[CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER] = true;
$curlOptions[CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT] = 30;
$curlOptions[CURLOPT_TIMEOUT] = 80;
$curlOptions[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] = $headers;
$curlOptions[CURLOPT_SSLVERSION] = CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1;
```

It gives the following error:

> Use of undefined constant CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1 - assumed 'CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1'

Please help me to resolve this error. What CURL SSL version I should use for this PHP version?

Comment: how are you passing the options to `curl`? with `curl_setopt` or `curl_setopt_array`

Comment: May be you just need to add missing quotes for the string ?

Answer (score 10):

There's actually a comment regarding this issue in the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/curl.constants.php#117258):

> Note that prior to PHP 5.5 following constants were missing and were available only through their numeric values:
>
> ```
> CURL_SSLVERSION_DEFAULT // 0
> CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1  // 1
> CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv2 // 2
> CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv3 // 3
> ```
>
> This was fixed after this support request: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62318

If you want to explicitly use TLSv1, simply supply `1` as an integer literal instead of the `CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1` constant.

However, unless the server you're connecting to requires a very specific version of the TLS protocol, it's usually fine to leave the cURL option at its default value and let cURL figure out the protocol by itself.

Answer (score 8):

I just added this to the top of my startup file:

```
// Add some missing constants
defined('CURL_SSLVERSION_DEFAULT') || define('CURL_SSLVERSION_DEFAULT', 0);
defined('CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1')   || define('CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1', 1);
defined('CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv2')   || define('CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv2', 2);
defined('CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv3')   || define('CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv3', 3);
```

...and now I'm all better, because, as [helmbert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1995300/helmbert) quoted, those constants are missing in PHP < 5.5.

Answer (score -4):

You should use

```
curl_setopt ( $ch , CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1 , true )
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, as your answer still uses the supposedly undefined constant `CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1`.

Comment: I had given this answer based on php.net standard document.